# can we use timer in taps?

Tags: iphone

i m working on app,in which user taps to shoot bullets,
i want user to restrict their taps,
like he next tap or touch should be counted after 1 or 3 seconds,

is their any snippet,i can use to rtestrict user for continiously tapoping/touch?

quick reply is aleways appreciated/
regards
shishir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSTimer object like this.

Create flag in your class `BOOL restrictTap;`

Add this methods:

```
// is your tap method
- (void) tap {
    if ( restrictTap ) {
        return;
    }

    // do your staff

    restrictTap = YES;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(enableTap)
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:NO];
}

- (void) enableTap {
    restrictTap = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking into the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/NSTimer_Class.pdf) class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

my code is something like this

if(bulletNo==-1)
    {
    bulletNo=6;

```
}
```

switch (bulletNo)

```
{
    case 6:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];
        bulletOne.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletThree.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFour.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFive.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletSix.hidden=FALSE; 
        break;


    case 5:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];
        bulletOne.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletThree.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFour.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFive.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletSix.hidden=TRUE;  
        break;

    case 4:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];
        bulletOne.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletThree.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFour.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFive.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletSix.hidden=TRUE;  

        break;

    case 3:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];
        bulletOne.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletThree.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletFour.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFive.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletSix.hidden=TRUE;  

        break;

    case 2:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];

        bulletOne.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletThree.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFour.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFive.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletSix.hidden=TRUE;  

        break;

    case 1:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];
        bulletOne.hidden=FALSE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletThree.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFour.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFive.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletSix.hidden=TRUE;  



        break;

    case 0:
        [self.audioPlayer play ];
        bulletOne.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletTwo.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletThree.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFour.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletFive.hidden=TRUE;
        bulletSix.hidden=TRUE;  

        reloadLabel.hidden=FALSE;

        [reloadbutton setHidden:NO];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

on every tap,bullet value get decrement by one.
i provided 6 bullet images,on each tap, bullet image gets visible and invidble,

now
for ex if bullets ==60;

now,when the value of bulleNo becomes 0 ,on each 6th tap,all bullets gets invisible,
so what i want is, wen all images gets invisble,i want to restrict user to tap. i already hv a shake function through which,when user shakes, all 6 images gets vissible.and wen all bullet images get visible,user start taps again...

hope m clear wat i want...
quick reply is always appreciated...
thanks anyways for replying dude.

Comment: it is not clear which view object is receiving the tap message. Which objects need to ignore tap messages?